# how to update score in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

i have done a quiz program.. can anyone help me how to show the score when the user clicks the wrong answer?? also as i have used random function,can anyone tell me how to avoid two options getting repeated as i have that problem as well..

```
import sys, pygame,random
from pygame.locals import *

#set up screen size
size1 = width, height = 600,600

# set up pygame, the window, and the mouse cursor
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size1)
pygame.display.set_caption('Know World Capitals')

#set up colors
WHITE=255,255,255
BLACK = 35, 35, 35
GREY=215,215,215
ORANGE=246,173,70

#screen color
background = pygame.image.load("bckgrnd.jpg")
backgroundRect = background.get_rect()
background2 = pygame.image.load("bckgrnd2.jpg")
background2Rect = background2.get_rect()

#set up fonts 
font1 = pygame.font.SysFont('ORW Gothic L',48)
font2 = pygame.font.SysFont('ORW Gothic L',22)
font3 = pygame.font.SysFont('ORW Gothic L',30)
#load game sounds
wow= pygame.mixer.Sound('wow.wav')
oops= pygame.mixer.Sound('lose.mp3')

#load first set of pics
a = pygame.image.load("b.jpg")
aRect = a.get_rect() 
aRect.topleft=20,200    

b = pygame.image.load("b.jpg")
bRect = b.get_rect() 
bRect.topleft=20,230

c= pygame.image.load("b.jpg")
cRect = c.get_rect() 
cRect.topleft=20,260

d = pygame.image.load("b.jpg")
dRect = d.get_rect() 
dRect.topleft=20,290

#load 2nd set of pics
f = pygame.image.load("a.jpg")
fRect = f.get_rect() 
fRect.topleft=20,200    

g = pygame.image.load("a.jpg")
gRect = g.get_rect() 
gRect.topleft=20,230

h= pygame.image.load("a.jpg")
hRect = h.get_rect() 
hRect.topleft=20,260

j= pygame.image.load("a.jpg")
jRect = j.get_rect() 
jRect.topleft=20,290

#load screen1 pic
e = pygame.image.load("fg2.png")
eRect = e.get_rect() 
eRect.topleft=175,100

#mouse pics
p=Rect(20, 200,215,30)
r=Rect(20,230, 215,30)
s=Rect(20,260, 215,30)
t=Rect(20,290, 215,30)
u=Rect( 545,475,70,31)

#a list of the 51  countries
S=['Jordan','Kazhakstan','Vietnam','Azerbaijan','Hungary','Libya','Seychelles','Cuba','Columbia','Venezuela','Madagascar','Israel','Qatar','Syria','Cyprus','Bahrain','Bulgaria','Belgium','Egypt','Barbados','Jamaica','Canada','Argentina','Chile','Peru','Honduras','Iceland','Saudi Arabia','Turkey','Thailand','Japan','India','Phillipines','Croatia','Greece','Romania','Finland','Russia','Lebanon','Uzbekistan','Bhutan','Bangladesh','Macedonia','Latvia','Ukraine','Slovakia','Norway','Poland','Lithuania','Mauritius','Kenya']
#a list of the 51 capitals
C=['Amman','Akmola','Hanoi','Baku','Budapest','Tripoli','Tripoli','Havana','Bogota','Caracas','Antananarivo','Jerusalem','Doha','Damascus','Nicosia','Manama','Sofia','Brussels','Cairo','Bridgetown','Kingston','Ottawa','Buenos Aires','Santiago','Lima','Tegucigalpa','Reykjavik','Riyadh','Ankara','Bangkok','Tokyo','New Delhi','Manila','Zagreb','Athens','Bucharest','Helsinki','Moscow','Beirut','Tashkent','Thimphu','Dhaka','Skopje','Riga','Kiev','Bratislava','Oslo','Warsaw','Vilnius','Port Louis','Nairobi']

#get random place form a list
def  getRanP(myList):
# This function returns a random state or capitol from the passed list.
key = random.randint(0, len(myList) - 1)
place=myList[key]
return place

#the game ends if this function is called
def terminate():
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()

#checks if player wants to quit the game
def waitForPlayerToPressKey():
    while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            terminate()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == ord('w'): # pressing escape quits
                terminate()
            return

#sets up grey colored text when given the text,font,surface and the x,y cordinates as attributes 
def drawText1(text, font, surface, x, y):
w = font.render(text, 1, WHITE)
v = w.get_rect()
v.topleft = (x, y)
surface.blit(w,v)

#creates black-colored text when given the text,font,surface and the x,y cordinates as attributes
def drawText2(text, font, surface, x, y):
w = font.render(text, 1, WHITE)
v = w.get_rect()
v.topleft = (x, y)
surface.blit(w,v)

#game screens
#set-up first screen
def screen1():
    screen.blit(background2, background2Rect)
pygame.mixer.music.load("www.ogg")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(0)
    pygame.display.flip()
waitForPlayerToPressKey()

#draw screen if player chooses a correct state
def screen3(cS,cC):
screen.blit(background, backgroundRect)
drawText1('Y o u   g o t   i t !...,',font1,screen,175,120)
drawText1(cC,font3,screen,250,210)
drawText2('i s   t h e   C a p i t a l    o f        ',font2,screen,125,245)
drawText1(cS,font3,screen,325,245)
drawText1('P  r  e  s  s     a  n  y      k  e  y     t  o    C  o  n  t  i  n  u  e  .  .  .',font2,screen,150,330)
drawText2('O r    P  r  e  s  s     W     t  o    Q u i t',font2,screen,165,385)
pygame.display.flip()
waitForPlayerToPressKey()

#draw screen if player chooses the wrong state  
def screen4(cS,cC):
screen.blit(background, backgroundRect)
drawText1('Oops!...,',font1,screen,175,120)
drawText1(cC,font3,screen,250,210)
drawText2('i s   t h e   C a p i t a l    o f        ',font2,screen,125,245)
drawText1(cS,font3,screen,325,245)
drawText1('P  r  e  s  s     a  n  y      k  e  y     t  o    Q  u  i  t  .  .  .',font2,screen,150,330)
pygame.display.flip()
waitForPlayerToPressKey()   


#check if player has clicked on the right or wrong state
def check(v,cap,s,cS): 
waitForPlayerToPressKey()
if C.index(cap)==S.index(s):
    #play sound and draw screen3 if player has clicked on the right state
    pygame.mixer.music.load("wow.ogg")
            pygame.mixer.music.play(0)
    screen3(cS,cap)
    changeCol()

else:
    #play sound and draw screen4 if player has clicked on the wrong state 
    pygame.mixer.music.load("lose.ogg")
            pygame.mixer.music.play(0)
    screen4(cS,cap)
    terminate()       



#main game screen                       
def changeCol():
pygame.mixer.music.load("next.ogg")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(0)
    capitol=getRanP(C)  
n=C.index(capitol)
y = random.randint(0, 4)
key=n
x=random.randint(0,5)
S[n]=S[C.index(capitol)]
cS=S[n]

screen.blit(background, backgroundRect)
drawText2(capitol+'   is the capital of ?', font1, screen,35,90)
#draw game-block choises on screen 
screen.blit(a,aRect)
screen.blit(b,bRect)
screen.blit(c,cRect)
screen.blit(d,dRect)
drawText1('C l i c k ',font2,screen,250,410)
drawText1('O n   t h e   S t a t e   t h a t   H a s   t h e   a b o v e   C a p i t a l',font2,screen,90,440)
drawText1('t h e n  P r e s  s   a n y   k e y  t o   C o n t i n u e . . . ',font2,screen,140,470)

#draw choises   

#randomly position the correct state in any of the choise blocks
if y==0:
    rdS1=S[n]
    rdS2=S[random.randint(0,17)]
    rdS3=S[random.randint(17,34)]
    rdS4=S[random.randint(34,50)]
    drawText1(rdS1, font2, screen,25,205)
    drawText1(rdS2, font2, screen,25,235)
    drawText1(rdS3, font2, screen,25,265)
    drawText1(rdS4, font2, screen,25,295)
    pygame.display.update()     
elif y==1:
    rdS1=S[random.randint(0,17)]
    rdS2=S[n]
    rdS3=S[random.randint(17,34)]
    rdS4=S[random.randint(34,50)]
    drawText1(rdS1, font2, screen,25,205)
    drawText1(rdS2, font2, screen,25,235)
    drawText1(rdS3, font2, screen,25,265)
    drawText1(rdS4, font2, screen,25,295)
    pygame.display.update()         
elif y==2:
    rdS1=S[random.randint(0,17)]
    rdS2=S[random.randint(17,34)]
    rdS3=S[n]
    rdS4=S[random.randint(34,50)]
    drawText1(rdS1, font2, screen,25,205)
    drawText1(rdS2, font2, screen,25,235)
    drawText1(rdS3, font2, screen,25,265)
    drawText1(rdS4, font2, screen,25,295)
    pygame.display.update()
else:
    rdS1=S[random.randint(0,17)]
    rdS2=S[random.randint(17,34)]
    rdS3=S[random.randint(34,50)]
    rdS4=S[n]
    drawText1(rdS1, font2, screen,25,205)
    drawText1(rdS2, font2, screen,25,235)
    drawText1(rdS3, font2, screen,25,265)
    drawText1(rdS4, font2, screen,25,295)
    pygame.display.update()
while True:
    #check which button the player clicks  
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            #return the poistion of the mouse
            z=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            #when the player clicks on a button,change color of the button to white, check if the state the player has chosen is right or wrong & then ask him another question
            if (p.collidepoint(z)):
                screen.blit(f,fRect)
                pygame.display.update()
                check(n,capitol,rdS1,cS)
            elif (r.collidepoint(z)):
                screen.blit(g,gRect)
                pygame.display.update()
                check(n,capitol,rdS2,cS)
            elif (s.collidepoint(z)):
                screen.blit(h,hRect)
                pygame.display.update()
                check(n,capitol,rdS3,cS)
            elif (t.collidepoint(z)):
                screen.blit(j,jRect)    
                pygame.display.update() 
                    check(n,capitol,rdS4,cS)


#main game loop
screen1()
changeCol()
```

Comment: What "score" are you referring to?

Comment: if some one gets a right answer, he gets one point..i want to count the right answers got by the user until he gets one wrong and want to show his score when he gets a wrong answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent double questions I would use another solution to you country/capital lists.
Instead of creating two lists I would create a dictionary like this:

```
d = {'Jordan':'Amman',
    'Kazhakstan':'Akmola',
    'Vietnam':'Hanoi',
    'Azerbaijan':'Baku',
    'Hungary':'Budapest'}
```

*EDIT after comment of dominic*

use this to get a different order each time you run the program without repeating options:

```
import random

countries = list(d)
random.shuffle(countries)

for country in countries:
    # Here your game code...
    print("Capital of {0} is {1}".format(country, d[country]))
```

Comment: *You will get another order each time you run the program*: That is not true. (Even if it is true for you with the current version of the python implementation you're using at the moment, you can't rely on it.)

Comment: maybe this is depending on the python version used? I do receive another order each time.. But I posted the random.shuffle solution too because I was not sure to rely on this..

Comment: @Dominic, it's an answer to his second question, because looping through a shuffled dictionary solves the issue of repeating options which he gets with the random solution he used.

Comment: Sure, my bad. You're right that if you use a loop you won't get duplicates.

Comment: thanks..and can you help me out how to update the score at the end of the game??

Comment: No problem, can you explain your issue with updating the score? I guess you can just start with score 0 and add 1 when the answer is right.. Next you can for example add the score as an argument to screen3 & 4 to show the current score... or is this not what you want?

Comment: i declare a variable called point=0 at the start of the program and increment it like point+=1 while checking if the answer is correct..but while running it, the program stops..i tried to give the increment in screen3 and screen4 also but the program stops when the answer is clicked and a key is pressed..can you help me when and how to give the increment???

Comment: You can start your `screen3` function with `global point`, and at the next line `point+=1`. This will update the point 'variable' set at global level. Next you can print the 'point' variable like this: `drawText1('Correct! points: {}'.format(points),font1,screen,175,120)` .. keep in mind that it's better to change the structure of your code because it's not a very neat solution

Comment: well i have just started to learn python and pygame and this was the best i could do...thanks for your help..

Comment: @joente: can you please enlighten me more on how to prevent repetition of questions using dictionary option??

Comment: I posted another answer which may help you with the repetition questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an example using a dictionary and generator to yield a random capital.

```
import random
d = {'Amman':'Jordan',
    'Akmola':'Kazhakstan',
    'Hanoi':'Vietnam',
    'Baku':'Azerbaijan',
    'Budapest':'Hungary'}

def gen_capital(d):
    "Generator that yields a random capital"

    # Get the capitals
    capitals = list(d)

    # Shuffle the capitals in a random order
    random.shuffle(capitals)

    # Yield all the capitals in the list one by one
    for capital in capitals:
        yield capital

def get_answers(countries, correct): 
    # Choose 3 random answers
    answers = random.sample(countries, 3) 

    # Make sure the right answer is in the answer list
    if not correct in answers:
        answers[random.randint(0, 2)] = correct
    return answers

random_capital = gen_capital(d)
countries = list(d.values())
```

In your code you can ask for the next captial using something like this

```
try:
    capital = next(random_capital)
except StopIteration:
    pass # All capitals are asked..
```

Next, get answers in a random order using `get_answers(countries, d[capital])`

*Note: I used 3 possible answers but I think it's clear how to change this in 4 answers.*

As an example/test you can loop through and see how this generates a random capital, with random answers without duplicates:

```
for capital in random_capital:
    print("{0} is the capital of ? ({1})".format(
        capital, ", ".join(get_answers(countries, d[capital]))))

# Budapest is the capital of ? (Hungary, Vietnam, Jordan)
# Baku is the capital of ? (Jordan, Azerbaijan, Vietnam)
# Akmola is the capital of ? (Kazhakstan, Azerbaijan, Jordan)
# Hanoi is the capital of ? (Vietnam, Jordan, Azerbaijan)
# Amman is the capital of ? (Hungary, Kazhakstan, Jordan)
```